# Allow a specific nested value to be updated in Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to give anonymous users the ability to update a specific value inside a nested architecture without giving permission on the rest of the document.

`events` is a top level collection and I update my document like so

```
update(`events/${event.id}`, {
  [`boardgames.${boardgameId}.votes.${uid}`]: true,
})
```

I have tried this solution

```
allow update: if ((request.writeFields.size() == 1) && ('boardgames' in request.writeFields));
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671227/allow-update-on-single-field-in-firestore) but it fails (both halves fails independently too).

What am I missing? Am I not updating only one field when 'going inside' a nested object?

It would be super helpful to be able to console.log the `request` and the `request.writeFields`.

Note that ideally I would like to only allow modification on the deepest property, the current user's `uid` inside the `votes`.

Comment: I am having the same problem, @MarcCoet did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I didn't. sorry. =/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `request.writeFields` captures the full path of the modified fields, so in your case it will be equal to `boardgames.${boardgameId}.votes.${uid}`.

You could use a regex with [String.matches](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches)

```
allow update: if request.auth.uid != null
  && request.writeFields.size() == 1
  && request.writeFields[0].matches("boardgames\.[^.]{5,25}\.votes\." + request.auth.uid)
```

Careful: request.writeFields is deprecated but unfortunately there is no good replacement for your problem